# How Doctrine determines default database connection?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, database-connection, doctrine-query

I am using Zend 1.11 with Doctrine 1.1.4. My application uses multiple databases.

In my bootstrap.php file, I've set up the details for two databases;

```
   $dbs = array(
        'global_users'=>array(
            'adapter' => 'mysqli',
            'params' => array(
                'host'     => 'localhost',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
                'dbname'   => 'global_users',
                'charset'   => 'UTF8',
            ),
        ),
        'search_landscape'=>array(
            'adapter' => 'mysqli',
            'params' => array(
                'host'     => 'localhost',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
                'dbname'   => 'search_landscape',
                'charset'   => 'UTF8',
            ),
        ),
    );
```

I've generated the Doctrine Model classes for the second database, search_landscape. I have not used the global_users database yet in the application whilst I have performed several Doctrine queries on the second database, search_landscape which is working as expected so far.

When performing the Doctrine queries, I am not defining an explicit connection to the database i.e it using the default connection,  how does Doctrine know which database to connect to?

When I start to use the other databases in the application I understand I'll have to define the Doctrine connection for each of them explicitly, however right now I have not defined any explicit connections yet Doctrine seems to know which db to connect to out of the two.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
```

Doctrine_Manager is a [singleton object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), you can set other connections as default using their names. See the [Doctrine_Manager API documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_manager.html) for more info.